# Magento url routing: how to locate the controller/views for a given url

Tags: magento, templates, model-view-controller, routes

I'm new to magento and I'm trying to find files/code based on this url:

```
somedomainfortesting.com/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=test
```

I just put a test domain name above for security purposes, but in general I'm just trying to find the file(views/controller) to the above url.  I'm new to magento.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's complicated, but generally speaking, Magento URLs have three parts (Zend Framework 1 style)

```
http://somedomainfortesting.com/index.php/front-name/controller-name/action-name
```

The "front name" generally identifies the module folder you can find a controller in.

For example, controllers for URLs with `catalogsearch` as the frontname can be found in

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/
```

You'd know this because in the `Mage_CatalogSearch` configuration file, there's a configued frontname (`<frontName>catalogsearch</frontName>`)

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/etc/config.xml
    <routers>
        <catalogsearch>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mage_CatalogSearch</module>
                <frontName>catalogsearch</frontName>
            </args>
        </catalogsearch>
    </routers>
```

The next part of the URL defined a controller name.  A controller name determines the specific controller file in the controllers folder.  Again, in your example the controller name is `result`, so you can find the controller in the following file (`ResultController.php`)

```
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php
```

Finally, the action name determine which method in the controller Magento will call.  In your example, there is no action name, so Magento defaults to the name `index`, which means it's `indexAction` that's called

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php
public function indexAction()
{
    //...
}
```

You'll notice above that I used the term *generally identifies* -- that's because there's lot of additional cases where multiple modules can claim a frontname, or users can rewrite URLs to go elsewhere.  If you're interested in learning more and digging deep -- my original [Magento for PHP MVC Developers blog series](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_for_php_developers) is still a good place to start (the content is dated, but still accurate).  If you're not bruised and battered after that, you can read [In Depth Magento Dispatch](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#dispatch) which covers how Magento handles URL routing, top to bottom.

Finally, and a little self servingly, you can checkout [Commerce Bug](http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net/) -- it's my commercial Magento debugging extension, and includes information on the specific controller for the loaded page.

[image]

You can use the free demo to easily see the Magento defaults, and [buy a copy](http://store.pulsestorm.net) for your own system if you think it would be worth it/useful.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, but I accessed the ResultController.php file and commented out everything, and I saw no change to the results page.  Is the template overriding magento core stuff by any chance?

Comment: @dave That's the trick of Magento -- it's going to depend heavily on your specific system.  Off the top of my head in your system 1. There might be a class rewrite; 2. You might be running in compilation mode. 3. Magento might be using a full page cache; 4. You might be running varnish. 5. There might be a local code pool override  That's why I built, and recommend Commerce Bug -- it will tell you specifically what your system is doing.  ( adding a `var_dump(get_included_files();` at the end of `index.php` may help you track down the specific controller file used)

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can find the template witch is renderig the content by enabling the path hits from here: System > Configuration > Developer, change Configuration Scope to Default Store View and than look for Path Hints setting and enable it.